# MS Access date conversion error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, date-formatting

My MS Access sql string is:

`select billdate from sales where billdate=#27/07/2014#;`

This string displays results as: 27/07/2014.

But, if I input

`select billdate from sales where billdate=#01/08/2014#;`

The string doesn't display any result.
But if I substitute billdate `#01/08/2014#` with `#08/01/2014#`
The string displays results as: 01/08/2014.

In the sales table, the date format for billdate column is `Short Date`.
My system date and time settings are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

I am actually using VB.NET. But the problem persists with Access rather than my VB code. I am using `MonthCalendar` object.

Kindly provide solution at database level if possible. If it is not possible then only give me the code at coding level.

Comment: Could you show the VB.NET code used to retrieve the record from the sales table. (OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand etc....)

Comment: Access requires an unambiguous date, I usually go for year/month/day. If there is any confusion, Access will treat a date as American format.

Comment: To avoid culture issues, you should not use the #. Instead, input all dates in your code as NEW DATE(??,??,??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to format your Value in VB.net.

Your string should build like this:

`Dim SQL as string = "select billdate from sales where billdate=" & Format(YourDate, "#yyyy\/MM\/dd#")`

Comment: I don't know why, but the code you suggested is actually working. I had always thought for it as a sql statement error. But now since the vb.net code is working... Thanks man.

Comment: I couldn't mention about the sql query because its very big. Just take a look here if you want.

Comment: Nice to listen that this helped you. The Access date format is really confusing, that's true.

Comment: `select a.billno, a.billdate, a.cid, b.cname, a.slno, a.pid, c.pname, a.qty, c.unit, (a.rate*a.qty)+(a.rate*a.qty*a.vat/100)-(((a.rate*a.qty)+(a.rate*a.qty*a.vat/100))*a.disc/100), a.callstatus, a.remarks,b.ph1,b.ph2,a.duedate from sales a,contacts b, products c where a.cid=b.cid and a.pid=c.pid and a.duedate=#" & Format(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start) & "# and reorder='Yes';"`

Comment: This was my code. The sql statement is as you see, very big. But I had problem only with the dates field. Thanks a lot.